# How to open SQLite3 database on pc after building it and retrieving from the device

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I have built an sqlite3 database on the device. When I retrieved it to the pc and tried to open it through Xcode, I got result_code 14, cannot open database.

I need to open this database and read from it while it exist on the mac. I was able to access it and read from it when it was on the device.

Comment: how you open the database through terminal or you have an Firfox sqlite manager...

Comment: I am not opening it through the terminal, I using objective c code and sqlite3 classes to open the database and accessing its content.

Comment: show me code what exact you done to aceess the content of database...

Comment: DB_OK = sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dDatabase); this is the line of code I use to open the database, db_ok is returning 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

**Create datbase... in Doc Directory..**

```
-(void)createdatabase
{
    NSString *databaseName = @"Card.sqlite";        // Name Of DataBase.

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDir = documentPaths[0];

    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(success)
        return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}
```

**Opening database and aceesss it's content..**

```
- (void)getData
{
    sqlite3 *database;

    NSString *databasePath;
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString *documentsDir;

    NSArray *documentPaths;

    databaseName = @"Card.sqlite";

    documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    documentsDir = documentPaths[0];

    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM Master";

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            [ID removeAllObjects];
            [Name removeAllObjects];
            [Image removeAllObjects];

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                [ID addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)]];
                [Name addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]];
                [Image addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)]];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

    [tblView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem is, I will never be able to enter the if statement, cause sqlite3_open is returning 14 instead of 0, meaning cannot open database. this is because I have built the database on the device and retrieved it from there, when I retrieved the database from the device seems a kind of security was linked to it to disable anyone to access it. I am able to access on the device but not outside.

Comment: I was supposed to build it using the simulator, but I"m facing problems there too. My question is: is there a way to overcome the security forced on the database.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, I copied it in the bundle and tried to access it from there. it is finding the database, but not able to open it.

Comment: the database is already in the document file what I need is to copy it to bundle using code. when I copied it to bundle before I had retrieved it from .xcappdata and I think this is why its not opening it. can I copy it to bundle through code?

Comment: because it only for your document folder if your app is deployed to new device you need to copy that database to that device document folder that's why this is necessary...

Comment: yes true, but where do I get the database from, it is on the first device, I need to have it in the bundle so when when I run the app on another device I install it to the document folder of the new device. I need to copy the database from the first device to bundle, then I can install it to other devices. (The copy of the database that I already have on the bundle I got it using .xcappdata, this is why I cannot access it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLite Manager Firefox Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to read database, or use [SQLiteManager](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14140/sqlitemanager)

You can find your .sqlite file at  : ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/User/Applications/ ...

Comment: thank you for your reply, I need to access the content of the database using objective c code, cause I'll be using it within the app. the database is a dictionary. I need to include it inside the application and access it. When it was on the device, once I built it I was able to access it. but I need to have in the application, cause it should be submitted with it.

Comment: If I had built it using the simulator I wouldn't have faced this problem cause I did it before, but the I'm facing some problems with my simulator, that's why I built it on the device and retrieved it from there, but it seems that the device leaves a kind of security on the database disabling anyone to open it.

Comment: My question is there a way to disable this kind of security?